# varray size can be a variable?

Tags: oracle, parameter, size

I need to create a varray, and its size must be a parameter of the procedure, for example

```
create or replace procedure x (cant number)
as
type arreglo is varray(cant) of number;
elarreglo arreglo :=arreglo();
begin
        elarreglo(1):=(9);
        ....
        ....
end;
```

I try to do this, but it shows this error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/24     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CANT" when expecting one of
         the following:
         <a number>
         The symbol "<a number> was inserted before "CANT" to continue.
```

what I'm doing wrong? Is possible to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be a variable, it must be a literal.

[Collection Variable Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/collection.htm#LNPLS01307)

[image]

> **size_limit**
>
> Maximum number of elements that the varray can have. size_limit **must
>   be an integer literal** in the range from 1 through 2147483647.